# Custom workflow call web service hosted in Azure through httpsend and use ADAL

Tags: workflow, azure

I am writing a custom workflow in SharePoint (Visual Studio) I need to call a custom web service hosted in Azure (secure).  In order to do this I need to use ADAL, however I cannot use code in the custom workflow.  How do I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here after a lot of digging around, its actually the last video.  This provides a very good example.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint-2013-workflow-web-services

Comment: You should post an answer, not a link to the answer, links will break or in this case the link requires payment.